# Reproducing an analog clock similar to the one provided by the ifsym package

Tags: symbols

### Situation

I was browsing [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) looking for a simple analog clock in which I could use in a pamphlet. At some moment, I found an interesting entry (page 91):

[image: Clock entry]

I tried to use the `\showclock` macro in my document, but unfortunately a `pdflatex` run showed me the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \showclock{4}{50}
```

In my Linux box with TL2011, the very same attempt to call `\showclock{4}{50}` gets even worse, with no `ifsym` package available.

### Documentation

I tried to read the documentation, but `texdoc ifsym` lists only a German document, of which I only understand a few words - sadly. (Ich spreche kein Deutsch.) `:(` Anyway, the icon table in the end of the documentation gives me the idea of a possible font problem, like a missing indexing or reference.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifsym}

\begin{document}

\showclock{4}{50}

\end{document}
```

### Question

Is there any package with a similar command, say `\clock{<hours>}{<minutes>}`?

Comment: I'm surprised you linked to the documentation on ctan, and not texdoc.net :)

Comment: @cmhughes: Oops, my bad. `:)`

Comment: only because I know you co-created `texdoc.net` :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}

\begin{document}
Il est minuit 45 : \showclock{0}{45}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. I feel so silly, I had no idea about providing a package option. Merci. `:)`

Answer (score 19):

It seems the `\showclock` command becomes available if you activate it with a `clock` package option:

```
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}
```

Answer (score 12):

For completeness sake, I'll add a honorable mention to a similar package I found when trying to find a solution to my original question: the `clock` package. According to the documentation:

- The basic command available is `\clock{<hours>}{<minutes>}` which takes two arguments: `hours` and `minutes`. It does not matter whether the hours are given in a 12h or a 24h range; the TeX clock understands both.
- When saying `\clocktime` (without any argument) then the TeX clock will output the current system time at time of compilation.
- `\ClockFrame`: a boolean parameter and can be `true` or `false`. Saying `\ClockFramefalse` lets the border disappear, saying `\ClockFrametrue` lets the border appear.
- The parameter `\ClockStyle` takes a number between 0 and 3 where 0 stands for a clock with invisible dial.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clock}
\usepackage[clock]{ifsym}

\begin{document}

\ClockFramefalse\ClockStyle=0\clock{13}{10}
\ClockFramefalse\ClockStyle=1\clock{14}{22}
\ClockFramefalse\ClockStyle=2\clock{15}{48}
\ClockFramefalse\ClockStyle=3\clock{7}{50}

\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=0\clock{11}{32}
\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=1\clock{12}{0}
\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=2\clock{8}{9}
\ClockFrametrue\ClockStyle=3\clock{1}{15}

\end{document}
```

The previous code creates the following output:

[image: Clock]