# Generate analog clock with numbered face

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to generate a clock similar to as in the question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49427/reproducing-an-analog-clock-similar-to-the-one-provided-by-the-ifsym-package)

But I want the face to be numbered. Is this possible with this package or any other?

Comment: As an aside -- if you're planning on producing a Roman Numeral clock, be careful to look at [*actual* RN clocks](https://www.google.com/search?q=roman+numeral+clock&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uWUtUrXrK8jb0QXIkIGYBQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1163&bih=817), as they sometimes have interesting features, e.g., most show 4 as "IIII" instead of "IV", and most also have the "feet" of each number pointing towards the center of the clock (making the six upside down).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A little variation of an example taken from the PGF documentation (Section **83
Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement**, page 912 for version 3.0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=cyan] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
  \node[font=\large] at (\angle:1.36cm) {\textsf{\xi}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (0,0) -- (120:0.8cm);
\draw (0,0) -- (90:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An perhaps one could define a command to control some attributes; below an example, allowing to specify the color, the radius and the font size for the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{2cm}O{\large}O{cyan}}{%
\def\radius{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=0.055*\radius]
\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius];
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
  \node[font=#2] at (\angle:0.68*\radius) {\textsf{\xi}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \draw[line width=0.04*\radius] (\angle:0.82*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
\draw (0,0) -- (120:0.4*\radius);
\draw (0,0) -- (90:0.5*\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\Clock\quad\Clock[1cm][\footnotesize][orange]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if this example has been removed from the documentation? I can't see anything obviously relevant on page 507...

Comment: @cfr It was page 507 on the manual for version 2.10. For version 3.0 it was moved to page 912. I've edited my answer updating the page and adding the name of the section in the hope of a more "stable" reference.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that was the case and hoped you might do something like that.

Answer (score 42):

We can convert Gonzalo's excellent answer in to a macro so that we can use it like:

```
\clock{<hour>}{<minute>}{<seconds>}
```

Further beautification is possible and left as a home work ;-).

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\clock[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!30] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red] at (0,.9cm) {TICK-TOCK};
\draw[rotate=90,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (-#1*30-#2*30/60:0.7cm); % hours
\draw[rotate=90,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-#2*6:1cm); % minutes
\draw[rotate=90,thin,red] (0,0) -- (-#3*6:1.2cm); % seconds
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%\syntax
%% \clock{<hour>}{<minute>}{<seconds>}
\noindent\clock{1}{15}{30} \clock{2}{25}{15}
\clock{12}{58}{10} \clock{6}{10}{45}


\end{document}
```

[image]

## Scalable version:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\clock[4][2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,line cap=round,line width=#1*3pt]
\filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!20] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
{
\draw[line width=#1*1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node[scale=#1]{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=#1*2pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red,scale=#1] at (0,.9cm) {TICK-TOCK};
\draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*2pt] (0,0) -- (-#2*30-#3*30/60:0.7cm); % hours
\draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-#3*6:1cm); % minutes
\draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*.6pt,red] (0,0) -- (-#4*6:1.2cm); % seconds
\path [fill=black] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%\syntax
%% \clock[<optional scaling dim>]{<hour>}{<minute>}{<seconds>}
\noindent\clock{9}{35}{55}\clock[1.2]{1}{15}{30} \clock[.9]{2}{25}{15}
\clock[.7]{12}{58}{10} \clock[.5]{6}{10}{55}
\clock[.3]{12}{20}{22} \clock[.2]{8}{0}{5}


\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a minimal animation. I don't dare to go for the inclusion of seconds hand / make the intervals small.

```
\documentclass[preview,border={10pt 0pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{clock.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \hdeg / \mdeg in {0/0,2/24,4/48,6/72,8/96,10/120,12/144,14/168,
16/192,18/216,20/240,22/264,24/288,26/312,28/336,30/360}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!30] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=2pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red] at (0,.9cm) {TICK-TOCK};
\draw[rotate=90,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (-\hdeg:0.7cm); % hours
\draw[rotate=90,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-\mdeg:1cm); % minutes
\path [fill=black] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
}

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex clock}

% convert to GIF animation
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 200 -loop 0 -density 400 -alpha remove clock.pdf clock.gif}

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
See the gif file in the same folder as this file.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't it be `\newcommand\clock[4][1]{%` (or the starred varsion `\newcommand*\clock[4][1]{%`) instead of `\newcommand\clock[4][2]{%`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg It was `\newcommand\clock[4][1]{%` originally. Now edited by MMA :)

Comment: Okay. Maybe you should edit it back then. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: It's OK. I don't mind. :-)

Comment: I just broke my watch, I think I will buy one of these... :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar You have already got mine hours ago... I wish I could upvote twice sometimes :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller: I know. I was just kidding ;) Thanks.

Comment: Your last clock is too big in both geometrical and file size.

Comment: @PSTikZ Sorry. It is a wall clock ;-). Geometrically, I was careless and file size, trust me, it could have been even larger ;-) let alone the time of compilation. I do have a almost full version, but, I hate it as it ran too long to compile.

Comment: Use PSTricks to overcome the long compilation issue with TikZ. ;-)

Comment: @PSTikZ: True. PSTricks is powerful than TikZ in some aspects. But you know, I am on the other side ;-)

Comment: I would like to see the code for the animation. `:)`

Comment: ...and I dare to compile it for you. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg There you go. It is the minimal (hence comfortable) code.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: Wow, we need this for the correct, current clocktime. But I am sure, you would have assembled this, if this is very easy. ;)

Comment: @Harish Kumar: An idea - could we not use, the `tdclock` package to get the correct numbers of hour, minute, second?

Comment: I am wondering: how can I add tiny minute labels from 1 to 59?

Answer (score 26):

Bit off topic-answer, once I made a "mathematican clock" as a birthday present. The result was printed out, and I replaced the number plate of a real clock with it:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a3paper,extrafontsizes,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[a3paper,margin=0.2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
        \draw [line width = 0.1cm] (\x:9cm) -- (\x:10.5cm);
    };
    \foreach \x in {0,6,...,360} {
        \draw [line width = 0.05cm] (\x:10cm) -- (\x:10.5cm);
    };
    \draw (0:0cm) circle [radius = 0.2cm];

    \node (1) at (60:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{9^{9-9}}$};
    \node (2) at (30:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{\dfrac{9+9}{9}}$};
    \node (3) at (0:7cm) {\Huge $\boldsymbol{\sqrt{\log_{9}{9^9}}}$};
    \node (4) at (-30:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{\sqrt{9}+\log_{9}9}$};
    \node (5) at (-60:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{\sqrt{9}!-\log_{9}9}$};
    \node (6) at (-90:7cm) {\Huge $\boldsymbol{9 - \dfrac{9}{\sqrt{9}}}$};
    \node (7) at (-120:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{\sqrt{9}!+\dfrac{9}{9}}$};
    \node (8) at (-150:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{9 - \dfrac{9}{9}}$};
    \node (9) at (-180:7cm) {\Huge $\boldsymbol{\sqrt[9]{9^9}}$};
    \node (10) at (-210:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{9 + \log_{9}{9}}$};
    \node (11) at (-240:7cm) {\Large $\boldsymbol{\dfrac{99}{9}}$};
    \node (12) at (-270:7cm) {\Huge $\boldsymbol{9 + \dfrac{9}{\sqrt{9}}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

(this is an excerpt, the original had also numbers 0-59 on each of the minutes line)

result:

[image: LaTeX results]

There are no hands, as those were provided by the real clock

Comment: You should typeset the birthday present correctly; `log` --> `\log`.

Comment: didn't knew there was a `\log` command. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle{3}
    \multido{\ia=60+-30,\in=1+1}{12}{\psline(2.9;\ia)(3;\ia)\uput{2.4}[\ia](0,0){\in}}
    \multido{\ia=90+90}{4}{\psline(2.8;\ia)(2.9;\ia)}
    \psline[linewidth=3\pslinewidth]{<->}(2.1;90)(0,0)(1.5;0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### A clock with exhausted batteries

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\multido{\is=90+-6,\ic=0+1}{60}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle{3}
    \multido{\ia=60+-30,\in=1+1}{12}{\psline(2.9;\ia)(3;\ia)\uput{2.4}[\ia](0,0){\in}}
    \multido{\ia=90+90}{4}{\psline(2.8;\ia)(2.9;\ia)}
    \pstVerb{/angle {\ic\space 2 mod 0 gt {90}{105} ifelse} bind def}%
    \psline[linewidth=3\pslinewidth]{<->}(!2.1 angle PtoC)(0,0)(!1.5 angle 90 sub PtoC)
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    \psline{->}(0,0)(2.2;\is)
    \pscircle*{2pt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious: Where is second's hand and it's Animation (your unique answer feature)?

Comment: Looks like `\psline[linewidth=3\pslinewidth]{<->}(2.1;90)(0,0)(1.5;0)` represends both hands.

Comment: Your second clock is broken. The hour hand points at 2:30, but the minute hand points at x:57.

Comment: @PSTikZ: Ah, I thought you meant that the second hand is decoupled from the minutes/hours.

Answer (score 4):

With Metapost.  This is more complicated than it has to be, because it takes care to mark off each minute, and to use different widths and lengths for five-minute ticks as opposed to one-minute ticks, but it's still pretty simple:

```
beginfig(1);

diameter=160;
radius=diameter/2;

pickup pencircle scaled 0.5;

z0 = (radius,radius);
z50 = (radius,diameter);

pair r[];
r[12]  = z50 shifted (0,-radius/4.5);
for i=12 downto 1:
    r[i] = r[i+1] rotatedaround (z0,30);
    z[i] = r[i];
endfor
defaultfont := "cmr17";
defaultscale := 1.5;
label("12",z12);
label("6",z6);
label("9",z9);
label("3",z3);
label("1",z1);
label("5",z5);
label("7",z7);
label("11",z11 shifted (0,-1pt));
label("2",z2);
label("4",z4);
label("8",z8);
label("10",z10 shifted (1pt,0));

pair p[];
pair q[];
numeric circangle;
circangle := 0;
p[0] = z50;
for i=0 step 1 until 60:
    p[i] = p[i-1] rotatedaround (z0,6);
    if (i mod 5 = 0):
        q[i] = 1/12[p[i],z0];
        pickup pencircle scaled 2;
        draw p[i]--q[i];
        pickup pencircle scaled 0.5;
    else:
        q[i] = 1/30[p[i],z0];
        pickup pencircle scaled 0.5;
        draw p[i]--q[i];
    fi
    draw p[i-1]..p[i];
endfor

endfig;
end;
```

I've always been partial to Metapost, as I find it much easier to program than tikZ.  tikZ does have the benefit of being able to be thrown into macros, though, as Harish Kumar's excellent answer above demonstrates.

I know that, strictly speaking, this isn't a TeX answer; but Metapost has such a pedigree among TeXnicians (even Knuth himself uses it for his figures, I'm told) that it seemed a fair answer to me.

Answer (score 4):

I'll leave my contribution here, using `pic`s to recreate Gonzalo Medina's clock with enough options to make it fancy but also simple to use:

```
\pic[opt] (name) at (x,y) {clock=HH:MM}
```

Some examples:

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\newcommand*{\oldrom}[1]{\ifnum #1=4 IIII\else\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@\fi}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
    hour pointer/.style={line cap=round, thick},
    minute pointer/.style={thin, line cap=round},
    ticks sep/.style={outer sep=-#1}, ticks sep={0pt},
    ticks size/.store in=\clocktickssize,
    ticks size=.25cm,
    ticks/.style={thin},
    main ticks/.style={very thick},
    clock/.style={draw, minimum size=4cm, circle},
    clock text/.code={\let\clocktext\textrm},
    hour pointer size/.store in=\hourpointersize,
    hour pointer size=0.5cm,
    minute pointer size/.store in=\minutepointersize,
    minute pointer size=0.75cm,
    clock text sep/.store in=\clocktextsep,
    clock text sep=1em,
    pics/clock/.style args={#1:#2}{
        code={%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\hourangle}{90-#1*30-#2*0.5}\pgfmathsetmacro{\minuteangle}{90-#2*6}
        \node[clock] (-clock) {};
        \foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
        {
            \draw[clock text, ticks] (-clock.\angle) -- ++(\angle:-\clocktickssize) node[anchor=center, shift={(\angle:-\clocktextsep)}] {\clocktext{\xi}};
        };
        \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270} \draw[ticks, main ticks] (-clock.\angle) -- ++(\angle:-\clocktickssize);
        \draw[minute pointer] (-clock.center) -- ++(\minuteangle:\minutepointersize);
        \draw[hour pointer] (-clock.center) -- ++(\hourangle:\hourpointersize);
        }
    }
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (Default) at (0,5) {clock=00:00};
\pic[hour pointer/.style={-{Kite[width=2pt]},
                         insert path={node[circle,
                                           minimum size=2pt,
                                           inner sep=0pt,
                                           fill=yellow!10,
                                           draw, thick]{}
                                     } },
     minute pointer/.style={{Circle[length=2pt]}-{Kite[width=2pt]}, shorten <=-.25cm},
     clock/.style={double=gray, double distance=2pt, draw, fill=yellow!10, circle, minimum size=3cm},
     clock text sep=0.6em,
     ticks sep=1pt,
     ticks/.style={shorten >=2pt}, main ticks/.style={shorten >=0pt, very thick},
     clock text/.code={\let\clocktext\textit}
     ] (Fancy) {clock=22:40};
\pic[right=1cm,
     clock text/.code={\let\clocktext\rom},
     clock/.style={minimum size=5cm, draw}] (Roman) at (Fancy-clock.east) {clock=16:33};
\pic[left=1cm,
     clock text/.code={\let\clocktext\oldrom},
     clock/.style={minimum size=5cm, draw}] (Old roman) at (Fancy-clock.west) {clock=12:30};
\foreach \clock in {Default, Fancy, Roman, Old roman} \node[above=.25cm] at (\clock -clock.north) {\clock\ Clock};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can anyone modify it to be scalable?

Comment: I believe it is scalable. However, you have to set linewidths and font sizes accordingly. (TikZ scaling do not scale font sizes and strokes).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version with MetaPost. This one give the current hour and minute at the time of the compilation, thanks to the internal variables `hour` and `minute` of MetaPost. Alas there is no internal variable in MetaPost which gives the current second, otherwise I would have also drawn a needle indicating it (but anyway, in this case the program would have been shown [in this subject](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236923/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face-add-seconds-roman-numerals/236957#236957)).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input mpcolornames
    r := 4cm; len := 10bp; min_thickness := 1.75bp; hour_thickness := 3bp;
    beginfig(1);
      path cadran; cadran = fullcircle scaled (2r); 
      fill cadran scaled 1.025; fill cadran withcolor .75[rgb_orange, white]; 
      % Graduation marks and labels
      for i = 1 upto 60:
        if i mod 5 = 0: 
          j := i div 5; angl := 90-30j; 
          freelabel("\large\sffamily\bfseries" & decimal j, (r-len)*dir angl, r*dir angl);
          draw ((r, 0) -- (r - len, 0)) rotated angl withpen pencircle scaled min_thickness;
        else:
          angl := 90 - 6i;
          draw ((r, 0) -- (r - .5len, 0)) rotated angl;
          freelabel("\tiny\sffamily" & decimal i, (r-.5len)*dir angl, r*dir angl);
        fi
      endfor
      % Needles
      label("\Large\scshape tic-tac", .65r*up) withcolor red;
      pickup pencircle scaled min_thickness;
      drawarrow origin -- r*dir(90-minute*6) cutends (0, 3.5len);
      pickup pencircle scaled hour_thickness;
      drawarrow origin -- r*dir (90-(hour+minute/60)*30) cutends(0, 6len);
      fill fullcircle scaled .75len;
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be typeset with LuaLaTeX. Current hour in Belgium:

[image]

Comment: To get current second, we can use lua code: `second := \directlua{ tex.sprint( os.date("*t").sec ) };`

Comment: @Dohyun Kim Great, thank you! Another incentive to learn Lua as soon as possible :-) I've included your code in the other subject: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236923/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face-add-seconds-roman-numerals/236957#236957

Answer (score 0):

Another 'boxed' clock.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=.4cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \filldraw[blue!50,draw=blue,line width=5pt] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
        \filldraw[white,draw=blue,line width=2.5pt] (0,0) circle(3.5);
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,11}{
            \filldraw[cyan] (30*\i:3) circle(.1pt) coordinate (a\i);
            \filldraw[cyan] (30*\i:2.75) circle(.1pt) coordinate (d\i);
            \draw[cyan,line width=1pt] (30*\i:2.4)--(d\i);
            }
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,59}{
            \filldraw[cyan] (6*\i:2.75) circle(.1pt) coordinate (b\i);
            \filldraw[cyan] (6*\i:2.4) circle(.1pt) coordinate (c\i);
            \draw[cyan,line width=.4pt] (b\i)--(c\i);
            }
        \foreach \i/\j in {2/1,1/2,0/3,11/4,10/5,9/6,8/7,7/8,6/9,5/10,4/11,3/12}{
            \filldraw[cyan] (a\i) circle(.24);
            \draw[blue] (a\i) node  {$\j$}; 
            }
        \foreach \i/\j in {0/3,9/6,6/9,3/12}{
        \filldraw[violet!70] (a\i) circle(.24);
        \draw[white] (a\i) node  {\bfseries $\j$}; 
            }
        \draw[blue,line width=6,-stealth] (-37.5:.4)-- (142.5:2.1);
        \draw[blue,line width=4,-stealth] (180:.4)-- (2.3,0);
        \draw[red,line width=1] (244:.4)-- (64:2.6);
        \filldraw[color=magenta] (0,0) circle(3pt);
        \filldraw[gray] (-.5,1.25) rectangle (.5,1.75);
        \node[white] at (0,1.5) (n) {\Large 10:15};
        \node at (0,-1.5) (m) {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{logoRS.png}};% use your picture
        \foreach \i in {-3.4,3.4}{
            \filldraw[blue,shade] (\i,3.4) circle(.15);
            \draw[black,line width=1.5] (\i-.15,3.4)--(\i+.15,3.4);
            \filldraw[blue,shade] (\i,-3.4) circle(.15);
            \draw[black,line width=1.5] (\i-.15,-3.4)--(\i+.15,-3.4);
            }
        \node at (2.9,-3.85) (c) {\tiny \copyright Raffaele Santoro 2/2022};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another 'boxed' clock.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=.4cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \filldraw[blue!50,draw=blue,line width=5pt] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
        \filldraw[white,draw=blue,line width=2.5pt] (0,0) circle(3.5);
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,11}{
            \filldraw[cyan] (30*\i:3) circle(.1pt) coordinate (a\i);
            \filldraw[cyan] (30*\i:2.75) circle(.1pt) coordinate (d\i);
            \draw[cyan,line width=1pt] (30*\i:2.4)--(d\i);
            }
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,59}{
            \filldraw[cyan] (6*\i:2.75) circle(.1pt) coordinate (b\i);
            \filldraw[cyan] (6*\i:2.4) circle(.1pt) coordinate (c\i);
            \draw[cyan,line width=.4pt] (b\i)--(c\i);
            }
        \foreach \i/\j in {2/1,1/2,0/3,11/4,10/5,9/6,8/7,7/8,6/9,5/10,4/11,3/12}{
            \filldraw[cyan] (a\i) circle(.24);
            \draw[blue] (a\i) node  {$\j$}; 
            }
        \foreach \i/\j in {0/3,9/6,6/9,3/12}{
        \filldraw[violet!70] (a\i) circle(.24);
        \draw[white] (a\i) node  {\bfseries $\j$}; 
            }
        \draw[blue,line width=6,-stealth] (-37.5:.4)-- (142.5:2.1);
        \draw[blue,line width=4,-stealth] (180:.4)-- (2.3,0);
        \draw[red,line width=1] (244:.4)-- (64:2.6);
        \filldraw[color=magenta] (0,0) circle(3pt);
        \filldraw[gray] (-.5,1.25) rectangle (.5,1.75);
        \node[white] at (0,1.5) (n) {\Large 10:15};
        \node at (0,-1.5) (m) {\includegraphics[scale=.1]{logoRS.png}};% use your picture
        \foreach \i in {-3.4,3.4}{
            \filldraw[blue,shade] (\i,3.4) circle(.15);
            \draw[black,line width=1.5] (\i-.15,3.4)--(\i+.15,3.4);
            \filldraw[blue,shade] (\i,-3.4) circle(.15);
            \draw[black,line width=1.5] (\i-.15,-3.4)--(\i+.15,-3.4);
            }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Image:**

[image]