# Draw Clock to help learn time

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fill

I am trying to draw a clock similar to http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/KUMON-Study-Wall-Clock-Learning-how-to-tell-time-easily-/252645374477 to learn how to use tikz on a full page diagram

I can draw the outer part of clock and labels, however I cannot figure out how to draw and colour the inner hours in the pink and yellow in the sample clock.

How do I create the 12 inner hour nodes so I can have each hour coloured yellow and pink?

I have completed the follwing code that attempts to draw the inner hours.  But I am unsure how to complete it so I can colour each node seperately

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\clock{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=white] (0,0) circle (10cm);
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270} %Draw 10 minute ticks
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:9.5cm) -- (\angle:10cm); 
\draw (\angle:9cm) node{\label};
}
%
% Replace the following bit to draw inners hours in node
%
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270} %Try to draw inner hours
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:6.25cm) -- (\angle:7.75cm);  %Draws part of inner hour
}
\draw (0,0) circle (6.25cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (7.75cm);
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {45,15,...,-285} %Draw inner hour
{
\draw (\angle:7.cm) node{\label};
}
%
% Replace the proceeding bit
%
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {84,78,...,-270} % Draw Second Ticks
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:9.75cm) -- (\angle:10cm);
\draw (\angle:9.5cm) node{\label};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=4pt] (\angle:9cm) -- (\angle:10cm);
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\clock
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions would be most helpful as I am not sure how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132321/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face/343524#343524

Comment: also related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236923/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face-add-seconds-roman-numerals

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just for fun, here is a solution using `contour` package...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand\clock[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[cap=round,rotate=90]
    % colors
    \colorlet{minutes color}{blue!50!cyan!70!black}
    \colorlet{bg hours 0}{yellow}
    \colorlet{bg hours 1}{red!50}
    \colorlet{hours color}{red!80!black}
    % styles
    \tikzset{
      minutes/.style={circle,inner sep=0,text width=5mm,align=center,font=\bfseries},
      minutes 0/.style={fill=minutes color,text=white,minutes},
      minutes 1/.style={text=minutes color,fill=white,minutes},
      minutes font/.style={font=\normalsize},
      hours/.style={font=\fontsize{60}{66}\selectfont\bfseries,text=hours color,align=center},
      mini hours font/.style={font=\fontsize{40}{46}\selectfont\bfseries},
    }
    % radii
    \def\bigradius{80mm}
    \def\minuteradius{75mm}
    \def\hourradius{60mm}
    \def\minihourminradius{25mm}
    \def\minihourmaxradius{45mm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\minihourradius{(\minihourmaxradius + \minihourminradius)*.5}
    \def\hourwidth{2mm}
    \def\minutewidth{1mm}

    % big circle
    \filldraw [fill=white,draw=minutes color] (0,0) circle (\bigradius);

    % minutes marks
    \foreach \angle[count=\c from 0,evaluate={\c as \hourmark using notequal(int(mod(\c,5)),0)}]
    in {0,6,...,354}{ \path (-\angle:\minuteradius) node[minutes \hourmark]{\c}; }

    % hours marks
    \foreach \angle[count=\c from 1,evaluate={\c as \col using int(mod(\c,2))}] in {30,60,...,360}{

      \path (-\angle:\hourradius) node[hours]{\c};

      \path[fill=bg hours \col]
      (-\angle:\minihourminradius) -- (-\angle:\minihourmaxradius)
      arc(-\angle:-\angle-30:\minihourmaxradius) -- (-\angle-30:\minihourminradius)
      arc(-\angle-30:-\angle:\minihourminradius) -- cycle;

      \path (-\angle-15:\minihourradius pt) node[mini hours font]{\textcolor{white}{\contour{hours color}{\c}}};
    }

    % hands
    \pgfmathsetmacro\hourangle{-#1*30-#2*.5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\minuteangle{-#2*6}
    \fill[rotate=\hourangle,fill=hours color] ++(0,\hourwidth) arc(90:270:\hourwidth) -- ++(50mm,0)
    -- ++(\hourwidth,\hourwidth) -- ++(-\hourwidth,\hourwidth) -- ++(-50mm,0) -- cycle ;
    \fill[rotate=\minuteangle,fill=minutes color] ++(0,\minutewidth) arc(90:270:\minutewidth) -- ++(70mm,0)
    -- ++(\minutewidth,\minutewidth) -- ++(-\minutewidth,\minutewidth) -- ++(-70mm,0) -- cycle ;

  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\clock{19}{45}
\end{document}
```

## Edit (specially for [Thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston))

To add the cat and the mouse, add the following lines...

... in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
```

... at the end of the `tikzpicture`:

```
\path (0:15mm) node[fill=cyan,circle,inner sep=0]{\Cat[3]};
\path (180:15mm) node[fill=lime,circle,inner sep=0,font=\fontsize{45}{50}\selectfont]{\ComputerMouse};
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, that's some neat code. I started trying to do the whole clock but it got a Little complicated with the filled blue Minute nodes... You handled it perfectly!

Comment: Wow.  That is an amazing example.  How long did that take to do?

Comment: Amazing! but where are the cat and the mouse?! (they are clearly visible on the OP graphic :-)

Comment: @Thruston Done... :-)

Comment: @StuartNorris about 15 minutes (+ 5 minutes to find the cat and the mouse).

Comment: Very nice solution. Small question. How can one change the size of the radius of the circles appearing over the 0, 5, 10,  15,...,55 minute marks appearing at the rim of the clock face?

Comment: @omegadot Modify the `minute/.style` defintion (use `text width=6mm` for example).

Answer (score 6):

You can draw a thick circle

```
\draw[line width=1.5cm, red!30] (0,0) circle (7.00cm);
```

and later on fill some sectors:

```
\foreach \i in {60,0,...,-240}
    \fill[yellow!30] (\i:6.25cm) -- (\i:7.75cm) arc (\i:\i-30:7.75cm)--(\i-30:6.25cm) arc (\i-30:\i:6.25cm)--cycle;
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\clock{%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=white] (0,0) circle (10cm);
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270} %Draw 10 minute ticks
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:9.5cm) -- (\angle:10cm); 
\draw (\angle:9cm) node{\label};
}
%
% Replace the following bit to draw inners hours in node
%
\draw[line width=1.5cm, red!30] (0,0) circle (7.00cm);
\foreach \angle [count=\label, remember=\angle as \last (initially -270)] in {60,30,...,-270} %Try to draw inner hours
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:6.25cm) -- (\angle:7.75cm);  %Draws part of inner hour
%\draw[line width=1.5cm] (\last:6.25cm) arc(\last:\angle:6.25cm);  %Draws part of inner hour
}
\foreach \i in {60,0,...,-240}
    \fill[yellow!30] (\i:6.25cm) -- (\i:7.75cm) arc (\i:\i-30:7.75cm)--(\i-30:6.25cm) arc (\i-30:\i:6.25cm)--cycle;

\draw (0,0) circle (6.25cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (7.75cm);
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {45,15,...,-285} %Draw inner hour
{
\draw (\angle:7.cm) node{\label};
}
%
% Replace the proceeding bit
%
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {84,78,...,-270} % Draw Second Ticks
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:9.75cm) -- (\angle:10cm);
\draw (\angle:9.5cm) node{\label};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=4pt] (\angle:9cm) -- (\angle:10cm);
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One other way is to test if `\label` is even or odd and do the filling accordingly:

```
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270} %Try to draw inner hours
{
\pgfmathparse{isodd(\label)}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
\draw[yellow, line width=1.5cm, line cap=butt] (\angle:7cm) arc[radius=7cm, start angle=\angle, delta angle=-30] node[midway, black]{\label};
\else%
\draw[pink, line width=1.5cm, line cap=butt] (\angle:7cm) arc[radius=7cm, start angle=\angle, delta angle=-30] node[midway, black]{\label};
\fi
}
```

That code also draws the hour labels, avoinding one extra `\foreach` you were using.

Here's an improved MWE, that uses the most outer circle as reference for the ticks, so if you chagen ist size almost the whole drawing adapts (only the colored circle doesn't.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%overlay, remember picture,
                    line cap=round, line width=3pt]
\node[circle, draw, minimum size=20cm, outer sep=-2pt] (Clock) {};
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270}{%Draw 10 minute ticks
  \draw[line width=1pt] (Clock.\angle) -- ++(\angle:-.5cm) node[shift={(\angle:-2em)}]{\label};
}

% Replace the following bit to draw inners hours in node
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270}{%Try to draw inner hours
  \pgfmathparse{isodd(\label)}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0%
    \draw[double=yellow!30, double distance=1.5cm, line cap=butt] (\angle:7cm) arc[radius=7cm, start angle=\angle, delta angle=-30] node[midway, black]{\label};
  \else%
    \draw[double=pink, double distance=1.5cm, line cap=butt] (\angle:7cm) arc[radius=7cm, start angle=\angle, delta angle=-30] node[midway, black]{\label};
  \fi
}

% Replace the proceeding bit
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {84,78,...,-270}{% Draw Second Ticks
  \draw[line width=1pt] (Clock.\angle) -- ++(\angle:-.25cm) node[shift={(\angle:-1em)}]{\label};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270} \draw[line width=4pt] (Clock.\angle) -- ++(\angle:-1cm);
\fill[red] circle (2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's. Now I understand what `line cap=butt` means. I was unsuccessfully trying with `rect`. That's the reason I used `fill` and not `draw`.

Comment: Your very welcome! There's an example in the manual that shows the difference. Another useful thing to know is that there's an arrow tip `Round Cap`, sometimes we want the round cap but don't want to add the extra `.5\pgflinewidth` at the end of the path... `:)`