# Giving text as a paramater to the image

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I simply modified the clock code in this link: [clock](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132321/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face)

Here is my code:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{1cm}O{\large}O{cyan}O{\textbf{}}}{%
\def\radius{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=0.055*\radius]
\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius] node {O\textbf{}};
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
  \node[font=#2] at (\angle:0.68*\radius) {};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \draw[line width=0.04*\radius] (\angle:0.82*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

I am trying to give my text as a parameter in these two lines:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{1cm}O{\large}O{cyan}O{\textbf{}}}
\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius] node {O\textbf{}};
```

by using O\textbf{}

Here is how I use this code:

```
 \quad\Clock[0.9 cm][\footnotesize][green][\textbf{my text here}
```

As a result, I see this image:
[image]

However intead of `O` in the middle of the clock, I want to see "my text here"
How can I do that?

Comment: you want a spec of `O{}` or `O{default text}` then use the argument `#4` so replace `node {O\textbf{}}` by `node {\textbf{#4}}`

Comment: when I tried that, I completely lost the file and could not see anything

Comment: OK I tried: ```\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{1cm}O{\large}O{cyan}O{default text}}``` and ```\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius] node {\textbf{#4}};
``` and it did not work for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of the command `\Clock`, I replace the 4th argument `O{\textbf{}}` simply by `O{}`.

As David Carlisle said in the comment to your question, replace `node {O\textbf{}};` by `node {\textbf{#4}};` (so the text is always bold in the clock). Here, `#4` is the 4th argument used when you call `\Clock`

Finally, I change your text "my text here" used when you call `\Clock` by the text "my text", because "my text here" is too long.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Clock}{O{1cm}O{\large}O{cyan}O{}}{%
\def\radius{#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect,line width=0.055*\radius]
\filldraw [fill=#3] (0,0) circle [radius=\radius] node [align=center] {\textbf{#4}};
\foreach \angle [count=\xi] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
  \draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:0.9*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
  \node[font=#2] at (\angle:0.68*\radius) {};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
  \draw[line width=0.04*\radius] (\angle:0.82*\radius) -- (\angle:\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\Clock\quad\Clock[0.9cm][\footnotesize][green][my text]

\end{document}
```

This code works with very recent LaTeX (before the 2022 version, please add `\usepackage{xparse}` in the preamble, before `\NewDocumentCommand`).

You obtain:
[image]